# How to change div background color with every step of input range?

Tags: jquery, html, input, native

I would like to define a color for every each step (10-15 of them max) in input type range. 
And on every step change, a div would change its' background-color.

Comment: Could you please post some code of things you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a handler to the input element's change event, and use a `switch` structure to decide which color to display.

```
$("input[type='range']").change(function(e) {
    var value = $(e.target).val();
    switch(value) {
        case "1":
            $("div").css({backgroundColor: "#AABBCC"});
            break;
        case "2":
            //and so on
    }
});
```

This could be useful if you need to do anything else with each value. If all you're doing is changing the background color, however, you could just use an array lookup:

```
var colors = ["#AABBCC", "#BBCCDD", "#CCDDEE", ...];
$("div").css({backgroundColor: colors[value]});
```

Comment: Hmm, that would be one veeeeery long switch statement

Comment: True. Maybe it would be better to just use an array with all the values.

Comment: The `{}` is not needed perse if you only change one CSS value.

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` takes two parameters or a map `{}`;

```
$('.slider').change(function() {
    var green = this.value(2);
    $('.bar').css("background-color", "#ff0000");
});
```

This won't change your background-color per slide-change yet of course. But you can probably figure that out on yourself. Your CSS function is fixed tho.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really understand your question but here is a try : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AL2tK/)
type something and move to the next... try deleting too....

**CSS:**

```
.done_class
{
background-color:green;    
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;    
}
.def_class
{
   margin:5px;
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   border:1px solid grey;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' class='change1' id='target1' />
<input type='text' class='change1' id='target2' />
<input type='text' class='change1' id='target3' />
<input type='text' class='change1' id='target4' />
            <br /><br />
<div id='target1' class='def_class' >target 1</div>
<div id='target2' class='def_class'>target 2</div>
<div id='target3' class='def_class'>target 3</div>
<div id='target4' class='def_class'>target 4</div>
```

**Script:**

```
('.change1').change(function(){
var id_change = $(this).attr('id');
var change_val = $(this).val();
if(change_val!='') {
$('div[id=' + id_change + ']').addClass('done_class').text(change_val);
} else {
$('div[id=' + id_change + ']').removeClass('done_class').text('target' + id_change);
}
});
```

Very simple - but works great.....

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Shlomi Hassid, but this is not what I was looking for. Cheers.